# How to properly call GroovyScriptEngine?

Tags: groovy

I'm testing Groovy but I can't figure out how to properly call GroovyScriptEngine. It keeps producing an error below.

> **org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingMethodExceptionNoStack**

Song.Groovy

```
class Song {

 def args;
{ 
  println "Song has been called." + args;
 }



 String getArtist(){    
    return "sdfsdf";
 }

 public String toString(){
    return "Hey!";
 }

 }
```

Java Main ->

```
String[] paths = { "C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\GroovyTest\\src\\groovy" };

        GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(paths);
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        Object s = "Default...";

        binding.setVariable("args", s);

        gse.run("Song.groovy", binding);
```

the args variable also produce null..

What to do ?

Comment: what is `Song.groovy` supposed to do? Your example looks like just a class declariation.  Also i'd expect that `args` to be bound toplevel for the script and your `Song.args` there is just `null` because that is a class member.

Comment: Just an example, lets say i wanted to call getArtist() from song class. Im actually confuse.

Answer (score 2):

You are loading a class!

If you want to test your class, try something like this in the end of your Song.groovy:

```
// Instantiate an object of your class and use some methods!
def song = new Song()
println song.getArtist();
```

When you run

```
gse.run("Song.groovy", binding);
```

You are basically loading your class, but you are not doing anything with it.

See this example [here](http://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html#_groovyscriptengine)

Comment: To sum up, GroovyScriptEngine requires groovy main method to execute method class. The binding property, in used to pass arguments to the method signature of main method of groovy.

Answer (score 1):

(Posted on behalf of the OP):

Working code:

**Test1.java**

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.util.GroovyScriptEngine;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] paths = { "C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\GroovyTest\\src\\groovy" };

        GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine(paths);
        Binding binding = new Binding();

        binding.setVariable("args", "Test Data");

        String result = (String) gse.run("File1.groovy", binding);
        System.out.println("Groovy Result: "  + result);

    }

}
```

**File1.groovy**

```
package groovy;

class Greeter {
    String sayHello(String data) {
        def greet = data;
        return greet
    }
}

 static void main(String[] args) { 
        def greeter = new Greeter()
        return greeter.sayHello(args);
   }
```